# Association data into json output in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, associations

I have a model where I can get my index action to return a list of objects back as json but I need each one to return a list of sub elements over an association.

I have tried the following but the coasters are not being output. Is there a way this can return each parks coasters?

```
  format.json do
    render json: Park.scoped(include: :coasters)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like :

```
render json: Park.joins(:coasters).select("parks.*,coasters.*")  # parks.*, coasters.* refers to actual table names
```

Comment: With this, I don't seem to get the Parks being returned?

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved with [active_model_serializers](https://rubygems.org/gems/active_model_serializers) gem.

Answer (score 0):

the code should looks like this

```
  format.json do
    render json: Park.scoped.to_json(include: :coasters)
  end
```

more info can be find here https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/2200